# How to set DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo and NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo to invariant?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, cultureinfo

I am refactoring some unit tests and found out that some parsing strategies rely on `DateTime.TryParseExact` and `sbyte.TryPase` which themselves rely on `NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo` and `DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo`.

In order to make my unit tests properly arranged, I decided to setup the `CurrentInfo` property of both `NumberFormatInfo` and `DateTimeFormatInfo` to their invariant flavours through:

```cs
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
```

However, out of curiosity I tried to check whether the respective `InvariantInfo` were setup through a unit test and turns out that no, they are not. I am wondering what I am missing here to have the `InvariantCulture` enforced in those those two `CurrentInfo`

```
[Fact]
public void ShouldReturnInvariantInfo()
{
    CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat = NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo;
    CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat = DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo;
    NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.Should().Be(NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);
    DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.Should().Be(DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);
}
```

Knowing that the underlying implementations:

`NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo`:

```
public static NumberFormatInfo CurrentInfo
{
  get
  {
    CultureInfo currentCulture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
    if (!currentCulture._isInherited)
    {
      NumberFormatInfo numInfo = currentCulture.numInfo;
      if (numInfo != null)
        return numInfo;
    }
    return (NumberFormatInfo) currentCulture.GetFormat(typeof (NumberFormatInfo));
  }
}
```

`DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo`:

```
public static DateTimeFormatInfo CurrentInfo
{
  get
  {
    CultureInfo currentCulture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
    if (!currentCulture._isInherited)
    {
      DateTimeFormatInfo dateTimeInfo = currentCulture.dateTimeInfo;
      if (dateTimeInfo != null)
        return dateTimeInfo;
    }
    return (DateTimeFormatInfo) currentCulture.GetFormat(typeof (DateTimeFormatInfo));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you right, you want to run some code (tests) under culture which is `Current` one, except `NumberFormat` and `DateTimeFormat` which are `Invariant`. If it's your case, I suggest to `Clone` the current culture and modify the clone:

```
// Current culture clone
CultureInfo testCulture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Clone() as CultureInfo;

// modified: current culture except Number and DateTime which are Invariant
testCulture.NumberFormat = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat;
testCulture.DateTimeFormat = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat;

// and, finally, set back as current
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = testCulture;
```

Let's have a look at formats

```
Console.Write(ReferenceEquals(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat,
                              CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat) 
     ? "Equals" 
     : "Not Equals");
```

**Outcome:**

```
Equals
```

**Edit:** In order to run code `using` the modified culture we can implement a *class* for it:

```
  public class TestCulture : IDisposable {
    private CultureInfo m_SavedCulture; 
    private CultureInfo m_TestCulture;
    private bool m_IsDisposed;

    public TestCulture() {
      m_SavedCulture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture; 

      m_TestCulture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Clone() as CultureInfo;
      m_TestCulture.NumberFormat = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat;
      m_TestCulture.DateTimeFormat = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat;

      CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = m_TestCulture;
    }

    protected vitrual void Dispose(bool disposing) {
      if (disposing) {
        if (!m_IsDisposed && ReferenceEquals(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, m_TestCulture)) {
          CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = m_SavedCulture;

          m_IsDisposed = true;
        }
      }
    }

    public void Dispose() => Dispose(true);
  }
```

And then use it as follows:

```
  using (new TestCulture()) {
    // Tests which should be run under the specific culture
  }
```